# Getting a value from a looped button

Tags: php

I have a php page that displays a div with some text and a button.
All information is from a database.
What I want to do:

I have an empty page I want to fill with the same text (from the same database row), but depending on which button is pressed, that text should show up.
For example: Button from article 3 is pressed, I want the page to be filled with the information from article 3.

I've thought of putting a value through each button but I can't find a way to make it work. 
Here's the code used in the php page I already have.

What code do I add, and what code should be used in the other page?

```
<?php
    include("db/connect.php");
    if ($connect->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT articleId, header, intro, content, author, date, img, articleLink FROM newsarticle";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <div class="newsreport">
            <p class="newstitle">
                <a href="<?php echo $row["articleLink"] ?>" class="titlelink"><strong> <?php echo $row["header"] ?></a></strong>
            </p>
            <p class="newscontains"> 
                <?php echo $row["intro"] ?> 
            </p>
            <img class="newsimage" src="<?php echo $row["img"] ?>">
            <br>
            <form action="<?php echo $row["articleLink"] ?>">
            <button class="newsbutton"> Lees verder.. </button>
        </form>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    }
    $connect->close();

    ?>
```

I've tried a few things like adding a value to the button itself

```
<button class="newsbutton" value="<?php echo $row["articleId"]; ?>">
```

But I have no clue how to get the value and make it so it links to the other page AND sends the right information through, making the right article show up.

I've thought of using sessions but honestly have no clue how to get on with them.

Comment: add hidden input field and when you will click that hidden fields value will be posted and you can know which button has been clicked

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your problem was understandable, but do post snippets of code that you have tried out with the button. Only then can we help you get to your end result.

Comment: are you looking to make the read more button of an article ? in that case you wanna show the content if the button is clicked ?

Comment: Yes, but the content has to be shown on another page. Which is why it makes it so hard for me to find a solution to, since the database looping messes up a lot of easy linking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use input **hidden**

```
   <form action="<?php echo $row["articleLink"] ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="YourName"  value="<?php echo $articleId ?>">
    <button type="submit" class="newsbutton"> Lees verder.. </button>
   </form>
```

other pages

```
 $IdArticle=$_POST['YourName'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM newsarticle WHERE articleId =".$IdArticle;
```

Comment: I think this gets close, but what code could I use to let the other page know what data to load in?

Comment: You can send ID article .and other pages can fetch data with where ID article

Comment: Editted the post just now, I've tried it, but I can't find a way to send the value of the button to the other page, while not looping it again

Comment: Never thought of post while fixing this, goddammit.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create hidden input field that will help you to understand what was clicked.

```
<form action="<?php echo $row["articleLink"] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="clicked button 1" name="button">
    <button class="newsbutton"> Lees verder.. </button>
</form>
```

Comment: This wouldn't really work due to the looping of the database right? It will return the same value for all buttons